# Repeat a part of JS & JQuery code for every file in a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dashboard for personal use that will be used only local (without any local server) with HTML + Javascript.

In a folder, I have a few `.txt` files and I want to read all of them and create separate select elements with the lines inside those texts.

I did it by reading one of the files (it works on Safari and Mozilla, but not on Chrome).

```
<script>

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", 'Messages/english.txt', false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                allText = allText.split("\n");

                var select = "<h4 style='color:white'>Messages</h4>";

                select += "<select class='textinputselection' style='width: 400px;'>";

                allText.forEach(function(item) {
                    select += "<option>" + item + "</option>";
                });

                select += "</select>";

                select += "<br><br>";

                $('#messages').prepend(select);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);

</script>
```

What I am trying to do now, is to do exactly the same for all the txt files in the folder "Messages" without the need of copy-paste the code for every file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function that you will only include once in the code :

```
<script>
    function doMyThing(file){
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    allText = allText.split("\n");

                    var select = "<h4 style='color:white'>Messages</h4>";

                    select += "<select class='textinputselection' style='width: 400px;'>";

                    allText.forEach(function(item) {
                        select += "<option>" + item + "</option>";
                    });

                    select += "</select>";

                    select += "<br><br>";

                    $('#messages').prepend(select);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

</script>
```

Then, each time you want to run this, you just have to add :

```
<script>
    doMyThing('Messages/english.txt');
</script>
```

for example :

```
<script>
    doMyThing('Messages/french.txt');
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to hard-write all the file names. I am looking a way to read the file names in an array and do what you said in a for loop :)

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLHttpRequest()` needs a full path so you must use another library to do that like [jquery.file.tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree/) this can help you.

but I recommend you getting the name of the files on server side, and sending the names to jquery and foreach on them (if you are dealing with this on server side).

if it's on client side, try file.tree to get all the names. and put all your function call in a foreach function.

Comment: As I said, this will be a dashboard for personal use and I don't want to install any local server for it. I will try the jquery.file.tree btw and see if it will help